# How to fix ggplot2 time series barchart bars that are too wide?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, timeserieschart

I am plotting a time series bar chart with a measure for different categories. When I plot the time series bar chart, the width of the bars fills over many dates so that the neighbouring bars touch, even if they are a month apart, but this means that it is unclear which date that bar corresponds to. How do I change the code so that the bars only appear over the date in the underlying dataframe?

I have successfully plotted another time series bar chart with exactly the same ggplot code but different underlying data and so it is unclear to me why this is happening with this particular dataframe.

In this following example, I use a dataframe with only one category for simplicity in highlighting the issue:

```r
data <- data.frame(a = c(as.Date("2019-05-30"), as.Date("2019-06-19")), b = c("FX FORWARD", "FX FORWARD"), c = c(29.2, 74.7))
colnames(data ) <- c("Expiration Date", "Security Type", "Exposure $M")

plot <- ggplot(data , aes(x=`Expiration Date`, y=`Exposure $M`, fill=`Security Type`)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + scale_x_date(labels = scales::date_format("%d-%b"), date_breaks = "3 day")
```

I expected the bars to appear only above the day in which they are stored in the dataframe and not as it is shown in the chart, i.e. $29.2 above 31st May 2019 only and not spreading from 23rd May to 8th June; same for the second data point. Can anyone advise how I may correct this in my code?

Thanks in advance for any help, I've tried looking all over for a solution.

Comment: It seems like putting bars over a date axis gets weird. `geom_bar`/`geom_col` has a width argument; for a discrete scale, that's the percentage the bar takes up across each discrete category. But for a date scale, it's the number of days (or maybe other units with the scale set differently?). So if you set `width = 2`, the bar will be the width of 2 days.

Comment: Beyond that, there's the fact that treating your dates as a continuous scale means breaks might not line up exactly with the dates in your data, so you may not get every date that has a bar labelled. In the case where you need every date labelled, you might be better off converting it to character.

Comment: Camile, thank you. This answered it. If I change part of the code to ```r geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 1)``` then it contracts the bar to only being over one unit of the x-axis.